# PHP form - post current URL as hidden value

Tags: php, email

I'm having troubles in getting the current URL from which the filled form was send.

I want to use the same form for more sites.

This is my form code:

```
<form method="post" action="send_c_box.php">
    <input type="text" class="textbox" name="meno" value="meno" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'meno a priezvisko';}">
    <input type="text" class="textbox" name="email" value="email" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'e-mail';}">
    <input type="hidden" name="current_url" value="<?php echo'http://',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>"  readonly/>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div>
        <textarea value="Vaša správa:" name="mytext" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Vaša správa...';}">Vaša správa...</textarea>
    </div>
    <span><input type="submit" name="submit" class="" value="Odoslať"></span>
</form>
```

And PHP that sends emails. I need its $message to show URL, but I couldnt get it to work by calling **$url**

```
<?php

header( "refresh:3;url=index.html" );

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $to = "szabo@atria.sk";
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    $first_name = $_POST['meno'];
    $url = $_POST['current_url'];

    $subject = "Správa z kontaktného formuláru";
    $subject2 = "Potvrdenie o odoslaní formuláru";
    $message = $first_name . " napísal vo formulári:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['mytext'] . "from" . $url;
    $message2 = "Dakujeme za odoslanie formuláru. V krátkom case Vás kontaktujeme.";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2);

    echo "Dakujeme za odoslanie vyplneného formuláru " . $first_name . ", za okamih budete presmerovaný spät.";
}

?>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and simply used **window.location.href**

```
<input type='hidden' id='currentId' name="current_url">
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('currentId').value=window.location.href ; 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

a solution would be to also use:

```
$thisUrl=$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'].'://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
```

Comment: for a more robust solution, you could also add the port `$thisUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . '://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . (empty($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']) ? '' : ':' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']) . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];`

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this is useless since it passes url of my php not the site form was send from.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that might help you :)

```
function get_current_url() {
  $pageURL = 'http';
  if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
     $pageURL .= "://";
  if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
     $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
  } else {
     $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
  }
  return $pageURL;
}
```

It works with http and https and it will return you your current url.

Comment: Sorry, but how do I make an output to my email with this?

Comment: Just call this function for the value of your hiden field and then get it from the post array

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have

```
<input type="hidden" name="current_url" value="<?php echo'http://',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>"  readonly/>
```

You're trying to concat the http:// string with a comma (,) instead a dot (.)

Try this

```
<input type="hidden" name="current_url" value="<?php echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Comma in your hidden input (after 'http://').
Must be:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="current_url" value="<?php echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>"  readonly/>
```